# private method in Transaction Spring Boot - Hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, transactions

I know that private methods can not be annotated with @Transactional in spring boot (it makes no difference), but my question is, if I call private method from public @Transactional method, does that private method will execute in same transaction?

Example:

```
@Autowired
PersonService service;

@PutMapping("/update-person")
public Person updatePerson(@RequestBody Person p) {
  return service.updatePerson(p);
}

@Service
public class PersonService{
...
@Transactional
public Person updatePerson(Person p){
   //private method
   checkValidPerson(p);
   ...
   p.setName("SomeName");
   ...
   return p;
}


private void checkValidPerson(Person p){
    //some code
}
```

Does here `checkValidPerson` will be executed in the scope of the same transaction that is opened at `updatePerson` method or it will open new transaction?

Comment: *Does that private method will execute in same transaction*  Yes

Comment: Every method you call will participate in the same transaction unless it is an external method call (call to other object) which has a different `@Transactional`.